# How can i know the relationship in the database in sql server 2008?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, relationship

I want to know how can I know the relationship in the database which is not determined by the primary key in the design

For example I have three tables in the database following like this :

- Table 1 : fields
- Table 2 : area
- Table 3 : location

and all of the tables have data but who created database did not explain the primary keys and the foreign keys in it, so how can i know the relationship between this tables?

Note : I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Should be on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no documentation at all and no defined foreign keys, your options are:

1. Look at the application source code to see what it's doing.  This may or may not be available to you.  If it isn't, you're in a fair bit of trouble.
2. Contact whomever wrote the application originally and ask them for help or documentation.  This may or may not be possible.
3. Guess.  I'm certain you'll have to do a lot of this no matter what.
4. Run the application while [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) is Trace Capturing the SQL queries sent to the DB, or using [Extended Events in SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630282.aspx).  I don't recommend running Profiler on a production DB due to the performance impact.  I've never used Extended Events, but I know that they're replacing Profiler's capture abilities in forthcoming editions of SQL Server.  Neither of these tools is particularly simple (Profiler isn't; Extended Events don't look any better from the doc).  You're going to need to read a fair bit of documentation.